# Extract FASTA sequences (with version number) using sequence IDs (without version number) listed in txt file

Tags: unix, awk, grep, extract, fasta

I would like to extract specific sequences from `myfile.fasta`  based on the ids listed in  `transcript_id.txt` file.
My main problem is that my transcript_id.txt file only lists transcripts ids while fasta file also has transcript versions and transcripts listed in transcript_id.txt can have multiple versions in fasta file.
I have tried several approach (listed below) but couldn't get what I need.

**myfile.fasta**

```
>transcriptA.t1
ATGGAAGTAGGAAGTGGTTTGGGGAATGATGAACGACGCACCTGGCCAGCCGATGTTCTA
GCAGCAGCAGATGCCTACGTTGTCCTCGCTGCAGAGTACAACCACAGCCTTCCCCCGGCA
AATCAAAGCATCCTAAATGAAGCATGTGTGACAGCAGGATCATCTGCCAGGGTTTCCAAA
CTCACCAACCTAATGGACCACTTCTTCTCGTACAAGTATCGTCCATCTGGCATTGTCTGC
TTGGCTGTTGAGACTTATGTCTGCTGGGGAGCTGAAGCACGCCTACATCTTTCACGCCTT
>transcriptA.t2
GTGCCAAATTGGGATCTGGAGAAACCTGCAGCTTTTGATCTTACTGTTGCATCACTGCTT
TTCATCAAGAAG
>transcriptB.t1
GGAGTGGTGAGTCTTCTGCTCACTGCACTAAACCTTAATGACACTGGGACCTACAGCTGC
GTTGATGTGCCTCAATCGATTGATGAATTTGCTCGGCGTCATCCTCGGCGATTGCAATTA
GTAGATATTCTTAACGATTGA
>transcriptC.t1
AAAAGGCTCTGGGAGTTTGAGGCCAACGGGGGGGGAGGCCCCATTACCTCCAGCGTCAGG
TTCGCTGATGTGTACAACGATGGAACCCTAGACGTGATCTTTGTCACCCTCACCGGAACC
TTCTGGGTCCTGGAGGGGCTCACTGGA
>transcriptD.t1
CAAAGGAAGCATGCCTCTAATGATGCTAAGTGCTCAGAGCTAGGTTGGTCATGCATACCA
GCCATGGGAGACCCGTCCCCATCCATCCAATGGAGCTCCACTCCGCAACTTTAG
>transcriptD.t2
ATGCCTCAGGTGAATGTGGCCCCACCCACTGCCAAGGTCAAGGGGGCGTGTAGGGTTGTA
TGTGGTGCGTTGTCTCTCCAACAATTCATTATGCCCGACCAAGAGGTGTCACCTGTTCAG
CAAGGAGAATCTGACCATTTGCACATTGAAGCTTTCACTCTGGTGTCTGGAGGCACGAGT
ACGGATGTCGTAACTTTGCTGCAAGAGCAATACAAAGTGCTAAGCTGA
>transcriptE.t1
TCTATTCCAGTAGTCTACAAGGCACTGACCCCTGAGGGAGTGCCATCCAACAAGGAAGAT
GTCATTGGAGTGGTGCCAGACAAGGTTGTTGGAACACCAGATGTGAAGCCAACTGGAAGT
GTAGCTGCTGCTGCTGCCTTGGGCGTGTGCAAAGTGACTCT
```

**transcript_id.txt**

```
transcriptA
transcriptC
transcriptD
```

**Goal**

```
>transcriptA.t1
ATGGAAGTAGGAAGTGGTTTGGGGAATGATGAACGACGCACCTGGCCAGCCGATGTTCTA
GCAGCAGCAGATGCCTACGTTGTCCTCGCTGCAGAGTACAACCACAGCCTTCCCCCGGCA
AATCAAAGCATCCTAAATGAAGCATGTGTGACAGCAGGATCATCTGCCAGGGTTTCCAAA
CTCACCAACCTAATGGACCACTTCTTCTCGTACAAGTATCGTCCATCTGGCATTGTCTGC
TTGGCTGTTGAGACTTATGTCTGCTGGGGAGCTGAAGCACGCCTACATCTTTCACGCCTT
>transcriptA.t2
GTGCCAAATTGGGATCTGGAGAAACCTGCAGCTTTTGATCTTACTGTTGCATCACTGCTT
TTCATCAAGAAG
>transcriptC.t1
AAAAGGCTCTGGGAGTTTGAGGCCAACGGGGGGGGAGGCCCCATTACCTCCAGCGTCAGG
TTCGCTGATGTGTACAACGATGGAACCCTAGACGTGATCTTTGTCACCCTCACCGGAACC
TTCTGGGTCCTGGAGGGGCTCACTGGA
>transcriptD.t1
CAAAGGAAGCATGCCTCTAATGATGCTAAGTGCTCAGAGCTAGGTTGGTCATGCATACCA
GCCATGGGAGACCCGTCCCCATCCATCCAATGGAGCTCCACTCCGCAACTTTAG
>transcriptD.t2
ATGCCTCAGGTGAATGTGGCCCCACCCACTGCCAAGGTCAAGGGGGCGTGTAGGGTTGTA
TGTGGTGCGTTGTCTCTCCAACAATTCATTATGCCCGACCAAGAGGTGTCACCTGTTCAG
CAAGGAGAATCTGACCATTTGCACATTGAAGCTTTCACTCTGGTGTCTGGAGGCACGAGT
ACGGATGTCGTAACTTTGCTGCAAGAGCAATACAAAGTGCTAAGCTGA
```

**Tried:**

https://bioinformaticsworkbook.org/dataWrangling/fastaq-manipulations/retrieve-fasta-sequences-using-sequence-ids.html#gsc.tab=0

**1) ncbi-blast/makeblastdb**

```
makeblastdb -in myfile.fasta -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
blastdbcmd -entry "lcl|transcriptA.t1" -db myfile.fasta -target_only
```

This partially worked but I could only search it by typing in exact transcript version and adding "lcl|".
Didn't manage to use wildcard or transcript_id.txt.

https://www.biostars.org/p/319099/

**2) grep**

```
grep -w -A 2 -f transcript_id.txt myfile.fasta --no-group-separator
```

This works great but I have to set **-A** to some number and numbers of lines each transcript has varies.

**3) Linearising fasta file**

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < myfile.fasta > linear.fasta
awk '/^>transcriptA/' linear.fasta
```

Again I don't know how to search linearised fasta file with transcript_id.txt only one by one using awk.

**4) seqkit**

This only worked if I *add transcript version to transcript_id.txt. Any attempt to use **--id-regexp** failed.

```
seqkit grep -n -f transcript_id*.txt myfile.fasta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
/^>/{
  found=""
  match($0,/^>[^.]*/)
  if(substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) in arr){
    found=1
  }
}
found
' transcript_id.txt myfile.fasta
```

***2nd solution:*** With using multiple field delimiters option.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
/^>/{
  found=""
  if($2 in arr){ found=1 }
}
found
' transcript_id.txt FS="[>.]" myfile.fasta
```

---

---

***Explanation of 1st solution:***

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when transcript_id.txt file is being read.
  arr[$0]                          ##Creating arr with index of current line.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/{                              ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  found=""                         ##Nullifying found here.
  match($0,/^>[^.]*/)              ##using match function to match regex starting from > to before dot occured in current line.
  if(substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) in arr){ ##Checking condition if sub string which we get after above succesul matched regex is present in arr
    found=1                        ##Then setting found to 1 here.
  }
}
found                              ##Checking condition if found is SET then print that line.
' transcript_id.txt myfile.fasta   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***Explanation of 2nd solution:***

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when transcript_id.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]                     ##Creating arr with index of current line here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/{                         ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  found=""                    ##Nulifying found here.
  if($2 in arr){ found=1 }    ##Checking condition if 2nd field is present in arr then set found.
}
found                         ##Checking condition if found is set then print line.
' transcript_id.txt FS="[>.]" myfile.fasta  ##Mentioning Input_file names and setting FS as > or dot for Input_file myfile.fasta here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that your transcript IDs listed in your text file don't include the version numbers. If your file of transcript IDs did contain the transcript IDs with version numbers, you could just use [samtools faidx](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-faidx.html) for this. Using the latest version of samtools (currently v1.11) all you would need is:

```
samtools faidx -r transcript_ids.txt myfile.fasta
```

So the actual problem just becomes: how to obtain a list of transcript IDs with version numbers? You could use any text processing tool for this. For example, using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F "." '
    FNR==NR { a[$0]; next }
    sub(/^>/, "") && $1 in a
' transcript_id.txt myfile.fasta \
\
> transcript_ids.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '
   FNR==NR {a[$1];next}
   substr($1,1,index($1,".")-1) in a
' transcript_id.txt RS='>' FS='\n' ORS='>' myfile.fasta
```